# If I play games on the Xbox 360 for too long will game discs get damaged?

Tags: xbox-360

Can playing the same game for long, extended time periods damage the physical media for the games in any way? I've been playing the same game (GTA V) for 5 hours now. I love this game and don't want to lose it, so I'd like to know if I should let it rest for a bit.

Comment: Whatever you do, do NOT tilt the console.

Answer (score 4):

Playing the game for extended periods of time shouldn't wear the game out any more than playing it a lot over a long period of time so long as your xbox is level. Basically the DVD is just spinning when data is being loaded and otherwise is sitting in the tray, which is what the disc is made for. Just keep an eye out for the fan doing 'too much work' or continual loud spinning of the disc. Basically, unless you hear odd noises or the xbox drastically changes its behavior, you should be fine. And if you hear odd noises, that probably means whatever could get broken already has been, and it's not from strain but just normal use.
*Also, make sure your vent ports are clear and your not playing in a room filled with dust. :)

PS. If you're really concerned, [you can copy your disc's data onto the hard drive (install the disc)](https://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-360/system/install-play-delete-game). That way load times are improved and your xbox doesn't need to read much data from the disc (only makes sure the disc is in so you can play the game).

Comment: Good answer, apart from the PS paragraph. While installing the game to hard disk usually improves performance, Rockstar have advised against installing the 'play' disk for GTA V for performance reasons. This is because loading both disks from the XBox 360 hard disk causes slowdown in access times.

Comment: I always install all my games onto the drive, since I have had a disc being scratched badly by the xbox. I did not notice any severe change in performance (good or bad), but it definitely does save your discs, since it only checks the disc to see if it is a legitimate copy of the game. Regardless of whether or not this is good for GTA specifically, but for all the games I have done this for, it works really well and is much much safer.